# How to set the throughput to 10000 RU for Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API in code

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

How to set the throughput to 10000 RU for Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API in code? Im using Mongo.Driver for .NET. Want to use something like db.RunCommand to set the throughput to 10.000 RU.

Comment: Why would you even think that was possible? CosmosDB support for MonoDB wire protocol is an "emulation", which means it's "pretending" to be MongoDB ( and quite badly from all accounts ). If you want to use CosmosDB settings then you need to use it's "own native API". Since MongoDB of course has no such setting, there would be no "command" equivalent. It's not a MongoDB thing. Use the native API for this.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the MongoDB API implements MongoDB functionality, while RU and [throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) are concepts in Azure Cosmos DB. Please don't get confused.

So, we have no way to set RU with the Mongo shell command line, which is not supported.

However, you could set RU in the Document DB SDK refer to the [official code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) as follows:

```
DocumentCollection myCollection = new DocumentCollection();
myCollection.Id = "coll";
myCollection.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/deviceId");

await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
    UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("db"),
    myCollection,
    new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 3000 });
```

Comment: `client` seems to be object of class `MongoClient`, referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-dotnet . If that's the case then it doesn't have a method named CreateDocumentCollectionAsync. Please clarify

Comment: @VivekDani CreateDocumentCollectionAsync is method in document db sdk,right?

Comment: ok, I was searching a bit. And I found it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentcollectionasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_CreateDocumentCollectionAsync_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_DocumentCollection_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_

Comment: what kind of connection string did you use when creating the client ? When I use connection string for mongo driver (the one that starts with mongodb://) to CosmosClient I get exception:  System.ArgumentException: The connection string is missing a required property: AccountEndpoint

Comment: Ok, found the solution. To change RUs for a database/collection, one needs to run custom mongodb command (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-custom-commands#update-collection) using mongo driver.